# does the distribution of all independent variables in a dataset need to be normally distributed to perform data analysis on it?

Tags: r, regression, supervised-learning

For my project that looks at if debtors will repay, I have a positively skewed target variable (with non-normal errors) which contains many zero values (which is a problem in itself) but after reading up about how to deal with the zeros, I saw many people asking about if all your independent features had to be normalized as well.

I am working in R, if anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated, with regards to both the normalizing of the dependent and independent features. Lastly, what is the result if you left all the data in their skewed form.

Comment: Neither the dependent nor the independent variable have to be normal distributed. In regression analysis, the residuals ("errors") have to be normal distributed. However, it could still be sensible to "normalize" (more precisely center and rescale) predictors. Also, if your dependent variable contains many zeros, you might have zero-inflated data. In that case, I'd suggest you look into hurdle models.

Comment: Suppose one of your independent variables was sex. What would it mean to say that sex is normally distributed?